# maven dependency rename jar with timestamp suffix

Tags: maven

The snapshot jars are suffixed with timestamp when using dependency plugin to copy them.

Does anyone know what went wrong?

```
[INFO] --- maven-dependency-plugin:2.5.1:copy-dependencies (copy-dependencies) @ pdfsec ---
[INFO] Copying test-3.5.9-SNAPSHOT.jar to test-3.5.9-20130726.002521-6.jar

        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>initialize</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <useSubDirectoryPerScope>true</useSubDirectoryPerScope>
                        <overWriteSnapshots>true</overWriteSnapshots>
                        <overWriteIfNewer>true</overWriteIfNewer>
                        <excludeArtifactIds>unboundid-ldapsdk</excludeArtifactIds>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Update to version 2.8 of the plugin and set the option [useBaseVersion](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/copy-dependencies-mojo.html#useBaseVersion) to `true`.

From the commandline:

```
mvn dependency:copy -Dmdep.useBaseVersion=true -Dartifact=x:y:z:p:c ...
```

(kudos to [Jens Kreidler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1075524/jens-kreidler))

Comment: Remind that using this plugin on command-line, the option is called "mdep.useBaseVersion", so use "mvn dependency:copy -Dmdep.useBaseVersion=true -Dartifact=x:y:z:p:c ...".

A small pitfall I just fell in :-/

Comment: Hi ! this question is pretty old but I still got a timestamped version when using unpack-dependency even with useBaseVersion set to true. This is not systematic however and sometime I have a -SNAPSHOT artifact...
Could be a bug in version 3.4.0 of the plugin ?

Comment: @ClémentHonoré  For me this happens, when you built the dependency locally or not. When Maven has to download it from a remote repo, it will use a timestamp. When you build locally, the dependency will have -SNAPSHOT on the local disk and Maven will just use that.

Comment: You're right, this is how it works.

Answer (score 1):

Stick `<uniqueVersion>false</uniqueVersion>` in there.

Comment: in plugin configuration?